# How to fix Android ADB push error: Directory not empty

Tags: android, push, adb

I am trying to put a .so file in /system/lib folder of emulator by using
`$ adb push /home/username/Development/newdroid/filename.so /system/lib`

but it gives me 
`error: failed to copy '/home/sudhir/Development/newdroid/libnfc_ndef.so' to '/system/lib/libnfc_ndef.so': Directory not empty`

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

try this command

> mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system